# How to remove "$" and "," from a price field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, input

I am saving a price string to my database in a decimal-type column.

The price comes in like this `"$ 123.99"` which is fine because I wrote a bit of code to remove the `"$ "`.

However, I forgot that the price may include a comma, so `"$ 1,234.99"` breaks my code. How can I also remove the comma?

This is my code to remove dollar sign and space:

```
def price=(price_str)
  write_attribute(:price, price_str.sub("$ ", ""))
  # possible code to remove comma also?
end
```

Comment: It would be better practice to store price as a number then format it as needed depending upon the view (with the "$" or whatever you need). Is that an option?

Comment: Agreed. A price is the type of value you might want to sum or manipulate mathematically. It should be a numeric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get there two ways easily.

String's [`delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-delete) method is good for removing all occurrences of the target strings:

```
'$ 1.23'.delete('$ ,') # => "1.23"
'$ 123,456.00'.delete('$ ,') # => "123456.00"
```

Or, use [String's `tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) method:

```
'$ 1.23'.tr('$, ', '') # => "1.23"
'$ 123,456.00'.tr('$ ,', '') # => "123456.00"
```

`tr` takes a string of characters to search for, and a string of characters used to replace them. Consider it a chain of `gsub` methods, one for each character.

BUT WAIT! THERE'S MORE! If the replacement string is empty, all characters in the search string will be removed.

Comment: oh ok sweet! So I could define that as a method and run it before save right?

Comment: or i could just straight throw it in there

Comment: I'd probably do it inline or massage the value inside the `price=` method. I wouldn't create a separate method to do it though.

Comment: Yes, I would just replace what you have with the recommended delete. But to be safe, be aware you might get passed a nil so something like this would be appropriate: `write_attribute(:price, price_str.to_s.delete('$ ,').to_f)`